# Count share numbers of product in Redis

Tags: mongodb, redis, database, nosql

I want to count the share numbers  and who shared it  of product ,

What type should I use to store in Redis? sorted sets?

I used sorted sets before, every product's share info store in ZADD('share','product id',0)

But now, I want to store who shared it.

It can be done in mongodb easily, but how to do it in redis?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in Redis? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Create another Sorted Set, or better - a Hash, which contains the Product IDs along with who shared them. That's if at most 1 user is able to share a product.

Answer (score 0):

If the order is not important, use for each product:

`SADD shares:<pdoruct_id> <user_id>`

If the order is important uniqueness isn't:

`LPUSH shares:<pdoruct_id> <user_id>`

If both the order and uniqueness are important:

`ZADD shares:<pdoruct_id> <current_unix_timestamp> <user_id>`

and then you'll be able to do

`ZREVRANGE shares:<product_id> 0 100` and get the users in the order they've shared the item.